# Push notifications only works in development gateway

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I've tried my push notifications with APN Tester Free 
[image]

```
when I try gateway development the notifications are pushed correctly, this is the log
2016-10-13 15:34:21 +0000: Disconnected from server gateway.push.apple.com:2195 
2016-10-13 15:34:21 +0000: Accessing gateway: gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 
2016-10-13 15:34:21 +0000: Connected to server gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 
2016-10-13 15:34:21 +0000: Set SSL connection 
2016-10-13 15:34:21 +0000: Set peer domain name gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 
2016-10-13 15:34:21 +0000: Keychain Opened  
2016-10-13 15:34:21 +0000: Certificate  data  for Apple Push Services: com.SoyPlus.SoyPlusPartner initialized successfully 
2016-10-13 15:34:21 +0000: Sec Identity created 
2016-10-13 15:34:21 +0000: Client certificate created 
2016-10-13 15:34:21 +0000: Connected 
2016-10-13 15:34:24 +0000: Token: <df11354b 3862f4fa 91cb260d 03375616 35662a44 91c09c23 7cb13b62 5e31157f> 
2016-10-13 15:34:24 +0000: Written 76 bytes sending data to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 

2016-10-13 15:34:24 +0000: Disconnected from server gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
```

And then notifications pops up
[image]

But now, when I change Gateway to AdHoc/Production I get no Push notification, this is the log:

```
2016-10-13 15:35:01 +0000: Accessing gateway: gateway.push.apple.com 
2016-10-13 15:35:01 +0000: Connected to server gateway.push.apple.com 
2016-10-13 15:35:01 +0000: Set SSL connection 
2016-10-13 15:35:01 +0000: Set peer domain name gateway.push.apple.com 
2016-10-13 15:35:01 +0000: Keychain Opened  
2016-10-13 15:35:01 +0000: Certificate  data  for Apple Push Services: com.SoyPlus.SoyPlusPartner initialized successfully 
2016-10-13 15:35:01 +0000: Sec Identity created 
2016-10-13 15:35:01 +0000: Client certificate created 
2016-10-13 15:35:01 +0000: Connected 
2016-10-13 15:35:02 +0000: Token: <df11354b 3862f4fa 91cb260d 03375616 35662a44 91c09c23 7cb13b62 5e31157f> 
2016-10-13 15:35:02 +0000: Written 76 bytes sending data to gateway.push.apple.com:2195 

2016-10-13 15:35:02 +0000: Disconnected from server gateway.push.apple.com:2195
```

How to fix this?, I've tried with both certificates provided (development and production)

[image]

---

**NOTE:** I've modified in Xcode Code Signing identity

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

after running it on my iPhone the issue still remains, do I need to publish in appstore and install it from there to make the full test?

Answer (score 0):

To use the production SSL  certificate, your app must be signed ( at compilation time ) with a Production Certificate. 
( the one used for the AppStore or the one use for AdHoc Deployment if you have an Enterprise Program )

Comment: I've updated my question, with suggestion you've made, just to ask if is it correct? can I run my app in Production Mode from Xcode???

Comment: No, you can't but you can submit to AppStore, and access to testFlight